# How to get the child width to not exceed the parent's width when parents width did not exceed its max-width value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The parent div's width did not exceed the value set in its `max-width` property. How to get child to inherit the actual width of the parent and not cause the parent to increase its width?

Comment: Can you please provide us with some code?

Comment: make the child have `width:100%`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I didn't really understand the question, but I think what you are searching for is this:

```css
.parent-el {
   max-width: 100px;
   width: 50px;
   border: 3px solid black;
}

.child-el {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="parent-el">
    <div class="child-el"></div>
  </div>
</html>
```

#### I set the child's width to 100%. If you set the child's width to 100%, the child's width becomes 100% of the parent's width. For example if the parent's width is 50px and you set the child's width to